# Open form with old combobox values

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, combobox

I'm building a Form on C# that stores data on an SQL server database.
I've added an open button which lets you open an old saved form from the form PK.

When I hit open, a new form is opened using `showdialog`, the data from the database is read using a data reader.

I'm getting the correct values in the Text Boxes , the **datetimepicker** tool.

However, when I try to show the value in the ComboBox of the opened form, I always get the first default value, but if I try to show it in the old form, the value changes.

The `dtr.GetString(1)` shows the correct value that I want to use.

```
Form1 Editing_Form = new Form1();
        int Result_ID_Number_int = Convert.ToInt32(Result_ID_Number);

    //Retrieve the data from sql server database and load them into the new form 
        try
        {
            sc.Open();         

            //READ PART1 FROM DATABASE
            string Get_Data_Query_1 = (" SELECT statement ");
            cmd = new SqlCommand(Get_Data_Query_1, sc);
            dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dtr.Read())
            {
                Editing_Form.Text_Subject.Text = dtr.GetString(0);
                Editing_Form.ComboBox_Organizer.Text = dtr.GetString(1);
        }

            dtr.Close();
 sc.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

### EDIT

I tried using the index, and I'm still getting the first value ( index -1 i think)

```
 string index_test = dtr.GetString(1);
Editing_Form.ComboBox_Organizer.SelectedIndex = Editing_Form.ComboBox_Organizer.FindStringExact(index_test);
```

PS: this is working for the main form, and not for the form that is newly opened, everything else ( text box , data grid view , check box ) are working fine and getting the values

Comment: You should not only set the Text portion or the ComboBox but also select the correct Item by setting SelectedIndex or SelectedItem! In fact when you do that you can leave the Text portion to the system..

Comment: @TaW i'm getting the index by comparing the string result value to all the list available in the combo box, and i'm getting the correct index value when i show it in a message box. But when i try to show it in the combo box i always get the first value, this is why i'm trying to do it as text and then setting it

Comment: When do you do this in the newly opened form? Maybe you are doing it too soon? (copying the code to a button is a good test for this..)

Comment: @TaW Yes, i'm opening a form from my main form, that will load old data from an sql database (like a way to show old forms values). If i use the code that i added in edit on the main form in the button that will open the new form, it works fine, but when i change it to fix the value in the newly opened form, i always get the default value. If i'm doing it too soon shouldn't the text box values also stay the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:
Did you supply a set of values to your combobox where the user can choose from? If you forgot to do this, then you will of course get index -1 always.

If you provided the value set to the combobox, then you may still get -1 if you query the SelectedIndex. The reason for this: You set the text property. An index >= 0 will only become active if the text matches one of the provided  texts **exactly**. It's not described on MSDN, but I am quite sure this includes uppercase/lowercase match.

Furthermore, you could create the preset-list of the combobox by adding (custom) objects instead of actual Strings. In this case, the String representation (output of .ToString()) is shown in the combobox, but I doubt that it is possible to compare that to a given String in the Text property.

Another possibility: Your database texts contain not-printable characters, that are not shown. Use the Length property of the strings to check for invalid data. Maybe you also have leading or trailing spaces, that need to bee removed by Trim().

However, for debugging you could select an entry from your combobox and use the selectedIndexChanged event to display information (the actual text, the selected index, ...) in a message box. In this way you may find failures in your data.

That's all ideas I have about your issue.

**EDIT**
After exchanging enough information in the comments which made you find the failure:
Your problem was that you created your form only. The Form_load() was not yet executed because that happens when the form is shown. Therefore your combobox did not contain any data when you had set the combobox' name property.
When you tested this in or as your main form, the combobox was very likely populated already when the value was set.
Thus the first paragraph in my answer actually was the right one, you and me just had to find out how and why...

Comment: I tried what you suggested, I think the problem is when I'm getting the value from the database and comparing it to the values in the combo box, the values aren't matching Editing_Form.ComboBox_Organizer.SelectedIndex = Editing_Form.ComboBox_Organizer.FindStringExact(dtr.GetString(1)); Is there a way to cast both values to the same type ?

Comment: How did you fill the combobox? with strings or with objects?

Comment: Try to set `Editing_Form.ComboBox_Organizer.SelectedIndex` to any value >= 0 to test if the combobox lets you change its index at all...

Comment: I filled them using a data reader             sc.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select Full_Name from dbo.MoM_Emp ORDER BY Full_Name ASC", sc);
            SqlDataReader R_1, R_2;


            //ComboBox1 -- Organizer
            R_1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt_1 = new DataTable();
            dt_1.Columns.Add("Full_Name", typeof(string));
            dt_1.Load(R_1);
            ComboBox_Organizer.ValueMember = "Full_Name";
            ComboBox_Organizer.DataSource = dt_1;
            ComboBox_Organizer.Invalidate(); sc.close()

Comment: If i use Editing_Form.ComboBox_Organizer.SelectedIndex to any value >= 0 i get an error (!INVALID ARGUMENT), if i put -1 i get the default first value

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, which also refers to combobox. There is a `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. Perhaps you also need to define the other one.

Comment: it's still not working, I am sure that this line of code ComboBox_Organizer.SelectedIndex =ComboBox_Organizer.FindStringExact(dtr.GetString(1)); is correct because when it is working for the main form and changing the combo box value, the problem is when i add the sub form name , example Editing_Form.ComboBox_Organizer.SelectedIndex = Editing_Form.ComboBox_Organizer.FindStringExact(dtr.GetString(1)); nothing happens

Comment: WHERE in the code do you fill the combobox? Does this actually happen before the combobox text is set? It should be in the form1_Load() or in its constructor then in your provided code.

Comment: The combo box data list are set in the form1_load(). After picking which old form i want to open, i take the values from the database and set them in editing_form (the new opened form) and into each control (textbox, datetime..). And after that i open the new form editing_form using Editing_Form.ShowDialog(); , where everything is loaded in the form except the combo boxes .

Comment: Try the whole program without any connection to your database. Use fixed values instead. I am confident you will get the same failure. Debug your code then by stepping over each line and checking the status of your controls.

Comment: I will , this will take some time thanks for your help

Comment: I moved my load_data() function inside form load to the initialize_components and everything worked, you caught my attention on that thanks :)

Comment: initialize_components() is created automatically by the VS designer. Take it to the constructor itself instead.

Comment: Everything is working really good now, that's for making me pay attention to that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below :- Add form focus or activete

1) Application.OpenForms[form.Name].Focus();

2) Application.OpenForms[form.Name].Activate();

3) This can be added when opening the child page like below ;-

var form = new Form1();

```
if (Application.OpenForms[form.Name] == null) 

{
       form.Show();
} 
else 
{
    Application.OpenForms[form.Name].Activate();
}
```

Thanks
Jitendra